# How to display element in LongListSelector only if bool=true?

Tags: windows-phone-8, boolean, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector binded to a ObservableCollection(MyObject) I want display an image inside a container (Grid) only if the myobject.BoolProperty=True. How can I do that ?
Unfortunatly it seems we can't access elements inside the LongListSelector from code behind...In my xaml page i want to display the image (IsSuscribed) only if the boolean property is true...

```xml
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="llsAllDoclibs" 
                                    LayoutMode="List" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                    HideEmptyGroups="False"    
                                    Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                    SelectionChanged="Doclibs_SelectionChanged"
                                    Margin="20,20,20,20"
                                    >

                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid   
                            Height="auto"
                            Margin="0,20,0,0" 
                            Background="White"
                            >

                            <StackPanel Margin="10,10,10,10">
                                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Source="/Images/BDocs/ico_action_valider.png"
                                       x:Name="IsSuscribed"></Image>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding NomDocLib}"
                                    Foreground="#FF00485A"/>
                                <TextBlock
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Text="{Binding NbrElements}"
                                    Foreground="#FF00485A"/>
                            </StackPanel>                            

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

**EDIT**

I implemented this code.It works fine.But I was wondering How can use this class with an int value.If the value >10 I want display my element otherwise I want to hide it. I try to replace the object value by an int but i had an error...

```cs
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
        {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
        {
            return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo language)
        {
            return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to your `Grid`:

```
Visibility="{Binding BoolValue,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

It should be fairly easy to write such converter (one line actually), but it is part of many frameworks out there.

Comment: Thanks for the code It works fine but actually i got an int value so i edited my question. Could you help me again pls ?

Comment: But you just wrote it? Just replace the code in the `Convert` function to suit yourself. The `value` parameter is of type `int` and it returns `Visibility` depending on the internal logic (like the `if` statement above. Also, rename the class then since it is no longer converter from bool to visibility.